# Generic "wavelet lifting" style matrix factorizations?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, algorithms, matrix-decomposition, wavelets

As context I will present the [wavelet lifting scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_scheme). In matrix terms it is a factorization of convolution that splits into two parts:

1. Predict ($P$) step.
2. Update ($U$) step.

$$S=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\U&I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&-P\\0&I\end{bmatrix}$$

Note the location of $I$ and $0$ block matrices, this means in practice that we have a *read-only* part of the vector and a *write-only* part of the vector.

This means the matrix multiplications can be done in complete parallel and in-place. Which is very nice for memory and modern CPU with many cores.

The whole transform (matrix multiplication) is then a concatenation of such "steps":

$$S = S_N\cdots S_2 S_1$$

with possibly unique $U_1,\cdots,U_N$ and $P_1,\cdots,P_N$:

$$S_k=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\U_k&I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&-P_k\\0&I\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Now to question, can we find an algorithm that would be able to find such a factorization not only for wavelet transforms but for *general matrices*?

Comment: is something missing after "this means the matrix"?

Comment: @kodlu yep you are right, I will fill it in. Thank you.